# Complete beginner question, merging vertices

Tags: modeling, vertices

So I've been trying to learn blender, and I wanted to make a gun model. I got a reference image, and I've been trying to merge some vertices in a way that looks like this:

https://i.imgur.com/rf3nrln.mp4

Unfortunately, the result looks like that:

[image]

https://i.gyazo.com/b30627e966835efebd77756330f7c54b.png

I could make it the hard way and connect the vertices from both sides like this:
https://i.gyazo.com/cac033f1ca0cc122a8bbcd666a763564.mp4

But it isn't really effective. Is there a way around it, or do I have to do it like that everytime? Sorry If my english is broken, but I hope you'll understand what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

edit: I've been trying to make that the images show up without entering the external links, but I couldn't do that, sorry!

Comment: Hi. For images to show up they should be added using the built-in uploader. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Alrighty, I'll keep that in mind the next time I'll decide to post something. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge vertices to corresponding vertices on another loop..

Select the sections of the loops you want to merge, (with an equal vertex count) 
 and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Bridge Edge Loops, with the 'Merge' option checked in the Tool region, or Options panel in 2.8.

[image]

as Ray Mairlot has commented, you may intend to merge vertices at opposite ends of existing edges.. in which case you would <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> select the edge ring, followed by <kbd>X</kbd> > Edge Collapse.

[image]

Comment: In this case it looks like ther eare already faces inbetween their vertices, in which case, *Edge Collapse* would be better.

Comment: @RayMairlot you could be right.. I'll edit...

Comment: Edge collapse worked, thanks for your help. I really appreciate it!